# Why do Western English-language philosophers(people*.) mostly present ideas(thoughts*) in a formal way? Linguistics, culture, thinking process, else?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, fallacies, philosophy-of-language

By formal I mean, unable to understand an idea, because of mistakes or logical fallacies that don't truly reflect on the idea itself.

When someone talks to you, it's possible to look not at sentence construction, but at why someone is telling you this. And if someone made any mistakes in their logic, it is possible to fix some fallacies to understand the idea. If we look for not the form, but the idea that's inside, we can clean view at the substance, despite the presence of extra or mistaken pieces of the puzzle.

Why do western people use mostly first method - formal one; but not second one - essence of the idea; and almost never both?

Second one is the **most logical**(*not most, just abstract, dialectic, going from another side to same, but without formal mistakes*) approach, maybe (I have to added more tags because I don't think that you will understand what I mean).

It looks like English is a topological body, and you need to say some keywords, to make others understand what part of the body you mean..

I draw attention to this: when I need to make the thought in English words, they become more formal and straight. Why? Also I notice this when I'm reading English texts.
How might you prevent this, when talking about metaphysics, for example?

Comment: People's ability to "look into" speaker's head is very limited, and their ability to fix speaker's mistakes is greatly exaggerated. The "essence" of the idea that one cannot spell out may not be all there in the head either, even when it seems that it is, so one should not expect others to figure it out for them. And if translating into English makes your thoughts more formal and straight (I suspect that translating into any foreign language forces one to straighten their thoughts) it is not to be prevented, it is to be celebrated.

Comment: My text was fixed by users, thanks, i keep most fixes, and some i keep in both variants: mine curve in parentheses and with *.

Comment: I agree, that this ability is limited (limited by what?), and the idea's essence was not all  there in the head (but can any idea be all there in one's the head?). But i told that it is two ways to look at anything, for example it can be thoughts. And i feel that Eng-specking people use mostly first way only. Also, when i read the text on Eng doesn't matter  it is mine or not, i look at its logic structure, and it is straight. I don't say that it is bad or good, but it is specific of what?

Comment: Do you mean [analytic philosophy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy)?

Comment: at start i meant all people, not philosophers, but one user edited my question people to philosophers. and while western philosophers speak Eng language, i need to agree with that Eng speaking people>Eng speaking bakers

Comment: people get frustrated easily. sometimes it feels like they are being deliberately so

Answer (score 4):

Western culture is stereotypically competitive in such a way that one tends to imagine that mistakes in the presentation of an idea are like "missing a field goal" or whatever, hence we often "jump on each other" for our mistakes rather than try to be sympathetic and working around the mistakes on our own end (flipside: hypocrisy, because we often don't treat our *own* mistakes so harshly, of course).

Now, that all is mostly a stereotype and there are also conflicts in/between other cultures; generally, humans frequently disagree for the sake of disagreeing, even if the meaning of what is being said is not really so different (e.g., there was an infamous debate within Christianity that turned on the presence/absence of the letter "i" in a word that was otherwise the same as the word used by the opposite camp of disputants; this is where we get the saying "it makes not one iota of difference"). Sometimes this is, implicitly, sexual posturing: the intelligentsia are stereotyped as not physically strong enough (on average) to physically compete so much, so they have to compete by mouthing off to one another about abstractions; winning a debate makes one seem like a more promising mate than the loser, etc.

**EDIT:** I've read, for example, that quoting sources without direct/clear attribution is not frowned upon so much in some countries, not because the cultures of the relevant nationalities are for some reason plagiaristic, but because there is an implicit understanding of attribution (readers who know that the quote *is* a quote are not misled, and there is an expectation that readers know such things without having to have every citation listed in a formal way). Alternatively, intellectual property rights, as a concept, are less demanding/less capitalistic in some societies, so competitiveness and self-adulation over these kinds of intellectual considerations is affected in a similar vein.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily unable, but maybe unwilling. Like often times discussions and arguments take up the form of debates and competitions where you didn't ask for another person's opinion but they delivered it anyway so the point isn't to sort out the problem but to show that the other is wrong.

So at the first sense of a fallacy you send them back to the rethink their argument and come back when they figured it out. Their job, not yours.

That is different than when you're actually inclined to learn something new, in that case you might still see the fallacies but you're more likely to work around them or call them out not as an attack but to clarify your understanding of a subject.

And last but not least sometimes ideas are just so complicated and huge or hard to describe that it's also easier for yourself if you can structure them and fit them into a formal scheme. Sometimes that reduction or focus alone reveals aspects that might have otherwise been hidden.

Comment: This is why computer programming is so interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Analytic philosophers and anyone engaging in analytic philosophy of the general sort will, or might, tell you that brevity, a lack of levity, and aversion to ambiguity (resolved or not) are all virtues in philosophical and truth making texts.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ambiguity/

> There are clearly words that are ambiguous but not (obviously) vague:
> ‘bat’ is not vague but it is ambiguous. ‘Is bald’ looks to be vague
> but not ambiguous... There is no guarantee that unambiguous utterances will result in full univocal clear understanding either

Learning when to (always) write clearly but with humour is actually quite joyful IME.

Comment: In the inverted time world, where lie is exist, all unambiguous utterances are lie.
postmodern = inverted time, and right now i ve proved the lie is exist.

Comment: @άνθρωπος i might run that through google translate a few times

Comment: i got "In a world of reverse time where lies are false, all unequivocal talk is false. postmodern = reverse time, right now I've proven false"

Comment: @άνθρωπος "There are ambiguous but ambiguous (obviously) ambiguous words: "Bat" is ambiguous but ambiguous." hahaha :D

Comment: Spam, spam, spam, spam. Spam, spam, spam, spam.... Spammity spam! Wonderful spam-biguous - *system halted*